# code for "separate and select it in object mode"

Tags: python, mesh

so i'm creating a macro out of separating selection in editor mode, and then select the separated mesh afterwards in object mode... i have very little knowledge of what i'm doing, but i'm doing it never the less...

so i need some help.  what would the code be for selecting the last separated mesh after coming out of object mode?  sorry if this doesn't make sense.  i wish blender would just select the separated mesh in object mode right after you separate it.  i don't know how to find the separated mesh basically.

How would i go about doing that so it would work every time with any object?  Thanks

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1449/15543

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to *store your selected object* name first and then deselect them after you separate the mesh.

Something like this:

```py
org_obj_list = {obj.name for obj in context.selected_objects}
# This is a Set comprehension in Python,
# which create a set of name from the context.selected_objects
# context.selected_objects will be a Iterable collection of some object

bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type = 'SELECTED')
# This will call the separate operator in your code directly
# the type can be a enum string in ['SELECTED', 'LOOSE', 'MATERIAL']

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
# Switch back to object mode from edit mode

# Those separated object will also be selected now
# We then check if selected object is the one we saved before, then deselect it.
for obj in context.selected_objects:
    if obj and obj.name in org_obj_list:
        # Deselect selected object
        obj.select_set(False)
    else:
        # Set the new created object to active
        context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
```

Not sure if this is the best practice, but it do work.

---

A custom operator:

```py
import bpy

class SeparateSelectionActive(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Separate object by selection and set it as active object."""
    bl_idname = "mesh.select_separate_active"
    bl_label = "Separate Selection Active"
    
    # An enum for prompt dialog
    separate_method: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items = {
            ('SELECTED', 'Selected', "Selected mesh"),
            ('MATERIAL', 'Material', "Based on material"),
            ('LOOSE', 'Loose', "Based on loose part")
        },
        name = "Separate Method",
        description = "Choose a method to separate mesh",
        default = 'SELECTED'
    )
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None and context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH'
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # Prompt to ask a method to separate
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def execute(self, context):
        org_obj_list = {o.name for o in context.selected_objects}
        
        # Separate using selected method
        bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type = self.separate_method)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        for obj in context.selected_objects:
            if obj and obj.name in org_obj_list:
                # Deselect everything selected before
                obj.select_set(False)
            else:
                # Set the new created object to active
                context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
                self.report({'INFO'},f"Set active object to: {obj.name}")
        return {'FINISHED'}

# A menu inject into View3D > Edit > Mesh tab
def _menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SeparateSelectionActive.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SeparateSelectionActive)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.append(_menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SeparateSelectionActive)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.remove(_menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_separate_active()
```

After register it as an Operator, you can search and run this operator in **edit mode** within 3d space:

[image]

Or in *View3d > edit mode > mesh > **Separate Selection Active*** after append a new menu function to make it searchable in Blender 2.90.

[image]

You should see a prompt asking a method for separating:

[image]

These options is exactly the same with original separate operator.

And this operator will separate it, deselected original mesh, make the new created mesh active:

[image]

Note: If the separate process make the one you want to be active unchanged, this operator will active the wrong mesh since it's still the original mesh with the same name.

Comment: hey HikariTW, thanks for the reply.  uh, i've tried running this code but it doesn't show up when i search for it.  fyi i'm still in "learning mode" with python and blender.  would you mind telling me what i should do specifically to have it show  up in the search? i checked the register and ran the script to no avail.  thanks

Comment: @tinypeacock Did you enter the edit mode and search in the 3d view area? Notice that: `def poll(cls, context): return context.object is not None and context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH'` line. This is a safety for checking if context is correct to run this operator. And search method in Blender will hide those method which failed this test.

Comment: i think i'm doing something very wrong.  fyi this is my first month with blender, so i'm still somewhat clueless.  here's a gif of me failing to run it: https://imgur.com/a/PEddW1L

Comment: @tinypeacock Wait... what is that **search**? Is that Blender 2.90? [Imgur](https://imgur.com/vtri7US). Yes that is a 2.90 search, then I need to change the addon to let new search operator find it.

Comment: Would you want to use Blender 2.80~2.83 instead of 2.90 beta? The API change might not be that much but it will increase the problem you might meet when scripting, modeling as a new Blenderer

Comment: hmmmm, ok that makes sense then.  i got the 2.9 because of some of the newer tutorials i was watching.  I'll try it on 2.8 now.  how difficult is it to also alter one for 2.9? would love to know what changed in case i have to use it again in newer version.  if it's a pain then no worries

Comment: [Reference/Release Notes/2.90/Python API - Blender Developer Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Python_API). Not that much but this is one of the case. I update the addon snippet, and it should work in 2.90 now.

Comment: this is working!!! soo good.  thanks so much Hikari!

Comment: @tinypeacock if this has answered your question please consider accepting and upvoting.